# Product is showing according to the filter but layered navigation and count is not working according to custom filter

Tags: magento2.4.2

**I have found some plugin for this issue, but IndexBuilder.php not found in below path**.
Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search

```
  <type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\IndexBuilder">
            <plugin name="Custom_Layernavigation::CustomLayernavigation" type="Custom\Layer\Plugin\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\IndexBuilder" />
        </type>
```

**Please anyone have alternate way for this?**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this plugin or disable the module that is using the plugin to the IndexBuilder file